# Static Parameter in Pic32

Tags: microcontroller, c, microchip

I am developing for Pic32 platform. I want to know how I can declare static parameter knowing that this parameter will be used all over the file in my application. I have tried using static like this:

> static int test=0;

But it doesn't work. The test variable is not visible all over the file of project.

P.S: I want also to store the value of the test parameter (not volatile).

Comment: I can only assume that you are using C as this is not in the question.  Use a #define.

Comment: @David: It's C. Read the tags.

Comment: This is really just a generic C programming question that is the same on any platform, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how for example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  generic C programming rather than anything embedded specific.

Comment: If you want to have the parameter (variable) visible in the whole file then place the declaration outside of any function body. This will make it into what is known as a "global" variable. As a global variable you can drop the static attribute from its declaration line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a variable static causes it be initialized once, when the function is first called. It will then be saved in RAM until the next time its function is called. It does not make it global. Global variables are generally considered poor practice.